module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'clip'
I use Colab for coding and get this error:
AttributeError: module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'clip'.

I have tried to upgrade TensorFlow and Keras, but I still get the same error.I get this error when fit the model at first epoch.
how could I fix it?
import segmentation_models as sm
model_vgg16=sm.Unet(backbone_name=backbone,input_shape=(256,256,3),classes=4,activation="softmax",encoder_weights="imagenet",decoder_use_batchnorm=True,encoder_freeze=False )

model_vgg16.summary()

"""# loss and metrics"""

loss="categorical_crossentropy"

dice_loss=sm.losses.DiceLoss()
focal_loss=sm.losses.CategoricalFocalLoss()

focal_dice_loss=sm.losses.categorical_focal_dice_loss

metric=[sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5)]

"""# compile"""

lr=0.001
model_vgg16.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
              loss=[focal_dice_loss],
              metrics=[metric])

history = model_vgg16.fit(preprocessed_x_train, ytrain_categorical, epochs=20,validation_data=(preprocessed_x_val,y_val_categorical),batch_size=32)

Error:
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-887dcd97e6be> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model_vgg16.fit(preprocessed_x_train, ytrain_categorical, epochs=20,
      2                     validation_data=(preprocessed_x_val,y_val_categorical),
      3                     batch_size=32)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models/base/functional.py in categorical_focal_loss(gt, pr, gamma, alpha, class_indexes, **kwargs)
    276 
    277     # clip to prevent NaN's and Inf's
--> 278     pr = backend.clip(pr, backend.epsilon(), 1.0 - backend.epsilon())
    279 
    280     # Calculate focal loss

AttributeError: module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'clip'


where does the segmentation_models package come from? if it is what I think it is, it's 4 years old, abandoned, no longer compatible with anything.

Directly use TensorFlow clip_by_value()

! pip install keras==2.10.0 tensorflow==2.10.0

